# java.io FileOutPutStream - There are white spaces among chars. Why?

Tags: java, string, java-io

i want to write something with this code but after i run there are white spaces between characters. but in code i dont give space to string.

```java
import java.io.*;

public class WriteText{

public static void main(String[] args) {

FileOutputStream fos; 
DataOutputStream dos;

try {

  File file= new File("C:\\JavaWorks\\gui\\bin\\hakki\\out.txt");
  fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
  dos=new DataOutputStream(fos);

  dos.writeChars("Hello World!");
} 

catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

 }

 }
```

Output is (in text file) : `H e l l o   W o r l d !`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [writeBytes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeBytes%28java.lang.String%29)

```
dos.writeBytes("Hello World!");
```

Essentially, writeChars will write every character as 2 bytes. The second one you are seeing as extra spaces.

Comment: So did I, for that matter. Still trying to learn what the purpose of `writeChars` is...

Comment: Java docs says: "Writes every character in the string s, to the output stream, in order, two bytes per character. If s is null, a NullPointerException is thrown. If s.length is zero, then no characters are written. Otherwise, the character s[0] is written first, then s[1], and so on; the last character written is s[s.length-1]. For each character, two bytes are actually written, high-order byte first, in exactly the manner of the writeChar method." Who want extra one bit . Big question i think.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a FileWriter and a BufferedWritter instead; don't forget to close your buffer or dos when you're done with it.

```
        FileWriter file; 
        BufferedWriter bw = null;

    try {

        file = new FileWriter("C:\\JavaWorks\\gui\\bin\\hakki\\out.txt");
        bw = new BufferedWriter(file);

        bw.write("Hello World!");
    } 

    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    finally{
        try{
            bw.close();
        }

        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```